# How to make custom serve command?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I actually did this in my past project and it was working, but its a new version now which is **6.0**, and it was **5.8** that I used before.

So what I tried, I just created a command:

```
php artisan make:command CustomServeCommand
```

And I put these code inside the **CustomServeCommand** class:

```
protected function getOptions()
{
    return [
        ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host address to serve the application on.', '127.0.1.1'],//default 127.0.0.1
        ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on.', 80],
    ];
}
```

When I `php artisan serve` it does not working.

Actually, the code above were working in **5.8** version returning these line:

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.1.1:80>
```

---

My question now is how to make custom serve command in version 6.0:

Instead of `127.0.0.1:8000`, I want to serve `127.0.1.1:80`.

Anyone does know how to achieve this?

---

**EDITED**:

> Note: this is just to lessen the post, I don't intend to post codes in image.

And heres the **5.8** [image]

Here's the generated code in **6.0** [image]

Comment: I tried to update the version to 5.8 but still doesn't work. I decided to achieve this in version **6.0**. Anyone knows?

Comment: Have you registered this command in artisan i.e in ```app/Console/Kernel.php```

Comment: @snn what do you mean registered? as I said I created a command using `php artisan make:command CustomServeCommand`. please?

Comment: @charls in `app/Console/Kernel.php` file, did you registered the custom command?

Comment: For your command to be resolved by service container, it has to be specified in Kernel.php within commands.     ```protected $commands = [
    Commands\CustomServeCommand::class
];```

Comment: @snn do I need to Sir? because it's working in 5.8 without registering it. Hmm. I will try.

Comment: @snn I done tried it. but still doesn't work

Comment: It works in 5.8 without registering it because it's not really a command, it's just a class overriding one function in an existing command

Comment: You can use ```php -S localhost:8000 -t public/``` to start you local development server rather than using command which is doing the same.

Comment: In laravel 6.0 , try extending ServeCommand instead of Command .

Comment: @snn yeah forgot that. Thanks it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the `5.8` version you were **EXTENDING** the existing command that composer loads **before** your own and in `6.0` you are not

Extend the existing `serve` command like this

#### This is all what you need to have (delete the rest of generated code)

#### Tested in 6.0.0

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

class CustomServeCommand extends ServeCommand
{
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host address to serve the application on.', '127.0.1.1'], //default 127.0.0.1
            ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on.', 80],
        ];
    }
}
```

And **NOT** registering the command in `Console\Kernel`

Your port choice is a little bit odd so you have to do a couple of things

#### Stop services already using that port (assuming Linux)

```sh
sudo service nginx stop 
# or
sudo service apache2 stop
```

#### Execute the command with root priveleges

```sh
sudo php artisan serve
```

#### Result

```
~/Sites/laravel (master ✗) ✹ ★ ᐅ  sudo php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.1.1:80>
[Thu Sep 26 18:04:02 2019] Failed to listen on 127.0.1.1:80 (reason: Address already in use)
~/Sites/laravel (master ✗) ✹ ★ ᐅ  sudo service nginx stop
~/Sites/laravel (master ✗) ✹ ★ ᐅ  sudo php artisan serve 
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.1.1:80>
^C
~/Sites/laravel (master ✗) ✹ ★ ᐅ  php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.1.1:80>
[Thu Sep 26 18:04:23 2019] Failed to listen on 127.0.1.1:80 (reason: Permission denied)
~/Sites/laravel (master ✗) ✹ ★ ᐅ  sudo php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.1.1:80>
[Thu Sep 26 18:10:28 2019] 127.0.0.1:58714 [200]: /robots.txt
[Thu Sep 26 18:10:29 2019] 127.0.0.1:58716 [200]: /favicon.ico
```

#### PS: I personally advise against doing this, port 80 is the standard HTTP port and should not be used by built-in server

#### Note that the server will proxy the requests to a different local IP and port despite http://127.0.1.1 access

Also, I recommend giving [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/valet) a shot (available for both Mac and Linux) as it's easier to access `project.test` without any command

But nonetheless, I hope this helps

Comment: Sir did you actually tried this? As I said I'm using version **6.0**, theres a little bit difference on the generated codes inside **CustomServeCommand** class. I will update my post, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @charles yes and I tried it on `6.0.0`, if you only want to change the port, just extend the existing serve command, a copy-paste of my example should work

Comment: there is actually a **signature** to serve. see my edited post

Comment: Remove the **signature** and everything else except the `getOptions` method and it should work

Comment: error returned Sir ` Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'App\Console\C
ommands\InputOption' not found

  at D:\document\optodph\app\Console\Commands\CustomServeCommand.php:44
    40|
    41|     protected function getOptions()
    42|     {
    43|         return [
  > 44|             ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host addres
s to serve the application on.', '127.0.1.1'],//default 127.0.0.1
    45|             ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to ser
ve the application on.', ...`

Comment: bdw I'm using windows 7

Comment: Import the `InputOption` class `use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;` at the top of your class, please just copy-paste my code :')

Comment: another error `The command defined in "App\Console\Commands\CustomServeCommand" cannot hav
  e an empty name.
`

Comment: **DO NOT REGISTER THE COMMAND** remove it from the `$commands` array in `app/Console/Kernel.php`

Comment: done remove it sir but still returned an error `The command defined in "App\Console\Commands\CustomServeCommand" cannot hav e an empty name.`

Comment: You didn't, it's still registered (that's why the error knows it's a command).... BTW if you didn't change anything at all from 5.8, it would still work

Comment: No Sir. I removed it. take a look here Sir https://github.com/nunomaduro/laravel-desktop-notifier/issues/6 it said the **signature** is need why the it returns this kind of error.

Comment: You failed to understand that `CustomServeCommand` is not really a command, it's just extending the existing command that is already registered

Comment: I already removed `protected $commands = [ Commands\CustomServeCommand::class ];` but still returned an error `The command defined in "App\Console\Commands\CustomServeCommand" cannot hav e an empty name.`

Comment: Try `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan clear`

Comment: nah Sir, it's working now. I just copy-paste your code what the heck, it's the extend Command instead of ServeCommand. Thanks Sir

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass it as a parameter?

For port 8000:

```sh
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

And if you want to run it on port 80, you probably need to use it with sudo:

```sh
sudo php artisan serve --port=80
```

Comment: actually know that. I just want to `php artisan serve` and it will serve my desired host and port using the custom command like I did in 5.8 version. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I `php artisan serve` no error but it serve *127.0.0.1:8000*. Supposedly should serve *127.0.1.1:80* like before in version **5.8**.

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the full `CustomServeCommand` class?

Comment: Ok, just give me a moment. I'll try to reproduce it on my local machine